# Missing argument for Parameter 'Coder' in call in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

Need to initialize an object, but my initializer isn't cooperating. I've got this so far but I'm not sure how to pass parameters to my object initializer(s).

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder, caseImage: UIImage, inputName: String, inputDate: String) {
    self.caseImage = caseImage
    self.caseName.text = inputName
    self.caseDate.text = inputDate
    super.init( coder: aDecoder )
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

The initializer is being called by this code in another class:

```
func loadSampleData() {
    let Photo1 = UIImage(named: "retino1")!
    let case1 = TableCell(caseImage: Photo1, inputName: "John Smith", inputDate: "2015-10-18" ) //error
    patientCaseArray = [case1]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to what you posted, you have to pass in a decoder in your init statement.  The following is what you are trying to call, which is invalid because it doesn't exist:

```
TableCell(UIImage, String, String )
```

So you either need to create it:

```
init(caseImage: UIImage, inputName: String, inputDate: String) {
    super.init( coder: NSCoder() )
    self.caseImage = caseImage
    self.caseName.text = inputName
    self.caseDate.text = inputDate

}
```

or pass in NSCoder():

```
 let case1 = TableCell(coder:NSCoder(), caseImage: Photo1, inputName: "John Smith", inputDate: "2015-10-18" )
```

Comment: I tried both methods, the first results in a different error. The other results on no change. With the first I get: Type NSCoder does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'.

Comment: yes, You can't make NSCoders literally,  you need to create the actual item that is based on the NSCoder,  I just realized I should have told you to just ignore the parameter and call the init() instead of init(decoder)